# Насколько код соответствует стандартам ООП?

Tags: javascript, ооп, инспекция-кода

Только начинаю писать ООП, до этого писал только процедурно. Прошу пробежаться глазком по коду и оценить насколько код соответствует стандартам ООП. Код слайдера.

https://jsbin.com/vocapebehe/1/edit?output - пример

```
'use strict';
    function SliderOOP(options) {
    // Элементы слайдера
    this.sliderWrapper = document.querySelector(options.selector);
    this.slider = this.sliderWrapper.querySelector('.slider');
    this.sliderItems = this.sliderWrapper.querySelectorAll('.slider-item');
    this.arrowButtons = this.sliderWrapper.querySelector('.arrows-slider');

    // Системные методы
    SliderOOP.addMarginItems = function () {
        for (let i = this.quantitySliderItems - 1; i > -1; i--) {
            this.sliderItems[i].setAttribute('style', 'margin: 0 ' + this.marginItem + 'px;');
        }
    }
    SliderOOP.countSliderScrollWidth = function () {
        this.sliderScrollWidth = (this.quantitySliderItems * 2 * this.marginItem + this.quantitySliderItems * this.itemWidth).toFixed(2);
    }
    SliderOOP.countMargin = function () {
        return ((this.sliderWidth - (this.itemWidth * this.visibleItems)) / (this.visibleItems * 2)).toFixed(2);
    }
    SliderOOP.hundlerClickArrows = function (e) {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('left')) {
            this.leftSwipe(this.sliderWidth);
        } else if (e.target.classList.contains('right')) {
            this.rightSwipe(this.sliderWidth);
        }
    }

    // Внутренние методы 
    this.rightSwipe = function (translateX) {
        this.coords.sliderX -= translateX;
        if (Math.abs(this.coords.sliderX) > this.getMaxScroll()) {
            this.coords.sliderX = 0;
        }
        this.sliderSwipe();
    }
    this.leftSwipe = function (translateX) {
        this.coords.sliderX += translateX;
        if (this.coords.sliderX > 0) {
            this.coords.sliderX = -this.getMaxScroll();
        }
        this.sliderSwipe();
    }
    this.sliderSwipe = function () {
        this.slider.setAttribute('style', 'transform:translateX(' + this.coords.sliderX + 'px);');
    }

    // Внутренние  значения
    this.visibleItems = options.visibleItems;
    this.sliderWidth = this.slider.offsetWidth;
    this.itemWidth = this.slider.firstElementChild.offsetWidth;
    this.quantitySliderItems = this.sliderItems.length;
    this.marginItem = SliderOOP.countMargin.call(this);
    this.sliderScrollWidth = 0;
    this.coords = {
        x : 0,
        y : 0,
        oldX : 0,
        oldY : 0,
        sliderX : 0
    }

    // Запуск слайдера
    SliderOOP.addMarginItems.call(this);

    this.arrowButtons.addEventListener('click', SliderOOP.hundlerClickArrows.bind(this));
}

SliderOOP.prototype = {
    getItemMargin : function () {
        return this.marginItem;
    },
    getScrollWidth : function () {
        SliderOOP.countSliderScrollWidth.call(this);
        return this.sliderScrollWidth;
    },
    getMaxScroll : function () {
        return (Math.ceil(this.quantitySliderItems / this.visibleItems) - 1) * this.sliderWidth 
    },
    setVisibleItems : function (visibleItems) {
        this.visibleItems = visibleItems;
        this.coords.sliderX = 0;
        this.sliderSwipe();
        this.marginItem = SliderOOP.countMargin.call(this);
        SliderOOP.addMarginItems.call(this);
    },

}
const options1 = {
    selector : '.slider-1',
    visibleItems : 3,
    mode: 'default'
}
const options2 = {
    selector : '.slider-2',
    visibleItems : 2,
    mode: 'default'
}
let slider1 = new SliderOOP(options1);
let slider2 = new SliderOOP(options2);
```

Comment: Прочитайте описание метки "инспекция-кода" и приведите вопрос в соответствие указанным требованиям.

Comment: нет смысла _создавать_ методы вроде `SliderOOP.addMarginItems` внутри конструктора, так как в это случае они будут создаваться при и обновляться при каждом создании объекта. Вообще странно зачем постоянно вызывать эти функции с bind/call если можно просто добавить их в прототип