# Как описать функцию смены картинки слайдера в данном случае?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Нужна помощь в том, как описать функцию стрелочек "вправа" и "влево" на слайдере! Есть картинки, при клике на которые запускается непосредственно слайдер, на слайдере есть две стрелочки (стили добавлять не стал, просто два чёрных квадратика)! Вот непосредственно с ними и загвоздка:

```js
miniImg        = document.getElementsByClassName("img"); 
close          = document.getElementById("close"); 
bigSlideWrap   = document.getElementById("mstrbig");
bigImg         = document.getElementById("bigImg");
aL             = document.getElementById("arrowLeft");
aR             = document.getElementById("arrowRight");

for(var i=0; i<miniImg.length; i++){
    miniImg[i].onclick=function(e){
    bigSlideWrap.style.display="block"
    bigImg.src=e.target.src
  }
};

aL.onclick=function(){
  alert("Arrow left") //в этих фукнциях и есть вопрос
}

aR.onclick=function(){
  alert("Arrow right") //в этих фукнциях и есть вопрос
}

close.onclick=function(){
  bigSlideWrap.style.display="none"
};
```

```css
.mini-img-wrap{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.mini-img{
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.big-img-wrap{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
  display: none;
}

.close{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.big-img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: black;
}

.arrowRight{
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 99;
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
  display: block;
}

.arrowLeft{
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 99;
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mini-img-wrap">
  
      <div class="mini-img">
           <img src="https://www.stihi.ru/pics/2013/03/21/3655.jpg"           id="img" class="img" alt="">
      </div>
  
      <div class="mini-img">
           <img src="https://www.stihi.ru/pics/2005/12/19-543.jpg"           id="img" class="img" alt="">
      </div>
  
      <div class="mini-img">
           <img src="https://static.baza.farpost.ru/v/1536487862393_bulletin"           id="img" class="img" alt="">
      </div>

</div>

<div class="big-img-wrap" id="mstrbig">
      <div class="close" id="close">close</div>

            <div class="big-img">

                <div class="arrowRight" id="arrowRight"></div> 
                <div class="arrowLeft" id="arrowLeft"></div>

                <img class="big-img" id="bigImg" src="#" alt="">
           </div>
</div>
```

Если будет готовое решение, то хотелось бы его увидеть с текущими данными, если это не реально, то можно попробовать создать массив из значений этих картинок, лично я не понимаю пока, как можно получить доступ именно к текущей загруженной в слайдер картинке, и уже с неё каким-то образом начинать листать! Ответ просьба писать исключительно на нативном JavaScript, без использования синтаксиса библиотек!

Comment: Все зависит от того, какой эффект Вы хотите получить, но в общем случае это примерно так: заводите переменную index, которая будет содержать значение текущего слайда и функцию, которая в зависимости от того, какое значение у этой переменной соответствующим образом двигае,  скрывает или слайды. По кликам на стрелочки Вы меняете значение index и вызавыете функцию, которая описана выше..

Comment: [вот готовое вашего товарища по сайту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/980714/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9F)

Comment: @ Stranger in the Q , ну эффект я думаю понятен должен быть, мне нужно чтобы картинки менялись при клике на стрелочки! Собственно в этом то и проблема, я не знаю как привязать эту самую переменную index, точнее к чему? Ну вот кликнул я на одну из маленьких картинок, её src просто присвоилось src большой картинки, а как я этот индекс привяжу к этим действиям мне не понятно! сами картинки у меня же не проиндексированны, и как это сделать мне чтот тоже в голову не приходит!